# Issue of multicollinearity in R for glm analysis

Tags: r, regression, generalized-linear-model, model, multicollinearity

I was wondering if someone could help me with a statistical problem I have run into. Any help would be incredibly helpful.

Please note that for clarity, I have simplified the below description. It leaves out information such as weighting, or transforming variables.

I am conducting a project which investigates the association between the funding a hospital receives and the clinical need of that hospital. I am investigating whether it would be better to also include a measure of the deprivation level of the area. Analysis has four variables:

```
Output- measure of clinical need (a measure of how ill people are in the area)
Input_funding - measure of the funding
Input_deprivation - measure of deprivation level
```

Input_funding is a government formula which is calculated by six variables, including age of the local population level.

My plan was to conduct GLM analysis as follows:

```
Fit1 <- glm(data=df, formula = (Output~Input_funding))
Fit2 <- glm(data=df, formula = (Output~Input_funding + Input_deprivation))
```

I planned to calculate the adjusted R2 for the two models. The hypothesis was that r2(fit2) > r2(fit1), and therefore a consideration of deprivation in funding would improve current funding formulas, as they would more closely match clinical need.

Input_deprivation has been shown in multiple studies, when controlling for age, to be positively associated with output. However, as people living in more deprived areas are more likely to live in younger areas, in fit 2, Input_deprivation had a negative beta value.   I therefore need to adjust for age in the above analysis. This variable is input_age. My plan currently was to compare the R2 of the following models. The hypothesis would now be whether R2(fit4) > r2(fit3).

```
Fit3 <- glm(data=df, formula = (Output~Input_funding + Input_age))
Fit4<- glm(data=df, formula = (Output~Input_funding + Input_age + Input_deprivation ))
```

However, given that age is used to calculate input_funding, I wondered if this would be problematic (certainly would introduce some colliniarrity between input_age and input_funding, however as we're not interested in the coefficients, and rather the fit of the model, I'm unsure this is as big an issue?). Additionally, ideally I don’t want either fit to include age as its own variable, given age has such a large effect. However I see no other way to control for it. I thought of the option of using Input_age*Input_deprivation, however this has the separate terms Input_deprivation and Input_age included.   Any ideas as to 1. Whether this is an issue and 2. How else I could control for age would be hugely apreciated!

Comment: I am puzzled: you note that (a) "age has a ... large effect;" (b) "age is used to calculate input_funding;" and (c) you are "interested in ... the fit."  Don't those (i) imply that of course there's collinearity and (ii) compel you to control for age?  You ask about "options," but options to do what, exactly?  Not control for age?  Somehow "partially" control for it, whatever that might mean?  In short, whence originates the reluctance not to include age as a covariate?

Comment: You are asking for a help which makes this a broad question. What is your specific question? Are you asking whether collinearity is a problem? But, a problem for what? It is unclear why you are fitting these GLM models. If you are just interested in the fit of the model, then collinearity is no issue. You can create new predictor variables that are not correlated and you would end up with the same fit.

Comment: What is your model supposed to do, such that you are considering that including age as a variable is a bad idea? If it improves the prediction, then why is this a problem?

Comment: *"which investigates the association between the funding a hospital receives and the clinical need of that hospital."* A scatter plot of the two variables would already be good enough here. But somehow you wish to include other variables and investigate the relationship in combination with other variables? What is more precisely the purpose to do this investigation?

Comment: @whuber Thanks for the response I suppose so. I guess i was asking if there are any options which would not involve having to include age as a covariate (as it is already included in the measure of funding).

Comment: @SextusEmpiricus thanks for your respones. The aim of these models is to show that when accounting also for deprrivateion, models fit data better than when accounting for funding alone. The take away of this finding (if it does occur) would be that an areas deprivation should be considered in funding formulas, to improve the ability of funding formulas to match clinical need.

Comment: @SextusEmpiricus It would lead to simpler and stronger results just to show this simple finding, that just by adding deprivation results are improved. Thereore, it would be better to fit a model without age as a covariate, given that this will significantly improve model performance by itself. However, I don't see nay other option which would allow to control for the mediating effect of age on the relationship between deprivation and clinical need